# Hey guys can anyone tell me what size serpentine belt I need to by pass my ac compressor for a 2012 Infiniti Qx56

Tags: part-identification, infiniti, serpentine-belt, qx56

Hello I need the size serpentine belt to buy pass ac compressor for a 2012 Infiniti Qx56

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: An online source with unknown credibility says a Bando  7PK1275 will work.